# Is there a way to get the event target in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

For example, if I assign the same method to the onPressed properties of two different buttons is there way within the method to tell which button was pressed?

I see in the docs that onPressed is a VoidCallback so passing in a parameter seems out of the question.

Comment: Assign a different method to each buttons.

Comment: That is what I was wondering if I could avoid.  I was trying to avoid duplicating code.  I suppose I could have small intermediate methods that just call the primary method and pass in the needed information.  I'm new to Flutter so am not sure what is possible.

Comment: You can do something like `onPressed: () => myMethod("button1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Darky** says, you have to create a method an call from the onPressed event on the button passing a tag as argument.

Sometimes you need the context, so I put as an optional argument

```
// on regular buttons
onPressed: ()=> onPress( "button.menu")
// when you need the context
onPressed: ()=> onPress( "button.nav", context)
```

The method should be this

```
void onPress(String tag,[BuildContext context]){
   switch(tag){
   case "button.nav":
        // here the specific event for the tag = button.nav
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
    break;
    default:
        // here the default event
    break;
    }
}
```